# Freeze Top pane only if the Data exceeds certain number of Rows

Tags: excel, vba

I want to format my Report by using VBA.

I want the apply Freeze pane on the Worksheet only if there are more than 35 Rows. 
I need to show is that if the data exceeds one screen ( I am taking 35 rows), we should have a Freeze pane enabled. In any other case ( less than 35 rows of Data ) the Freeze Pane should be disabled.

I have used the below code for Freeze Top pane. How can i do the Part with the checking the Rows?

```
    new_book.Sheets("Report_").Range("A2").Select
    With ActiveWindow
        .SplitColumn = 0
        .SplitRow = 1
    End With
    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple... Get the last row, test if it exceeds 35. If yes, Freeze the Panes.

The below runs on the active sheet.

```
Sub Test()
Dim lastrow As Integer
lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

If lastrow > 35 Then
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks ! I just modified it a little and it worked- 

Dim lastrow as integer

lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

If lastrow > 35 Then

new_book.Sheets("Report").Range("A2").Select

    With ActiveWindow
        .SplitColumn = 0
        .SplitRow = 1
    End With
    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
End If

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Workbook_SheetActivate` Event in **ThisWorkbook** for this.

So Every Time you are switching the Worksheet, it will check if there are more then 35 Rows. When there are More it will Freeze the First row. Hope this will Help you.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)

    Dim intLastRow As Integer

    With Sh.UsedRange
            intLastRow = .Rows(.Rows.Count).Row
    End With

    If intLastRow > 35 Then        
        Sh.Range("A2").Select
        With ActiveWindow
            .SplitColumn = 0
            .SplitRow = 1
        End With
        ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
    Else
        Sh.Range("A2").Select
        With ActiveWindow
            .SplitColumn = 0
            .SplitRow = 0
        End With
        ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, but it worked without using Else..  so we may ignore the Else condition..

Comment: The else Condition was inserted, if you would delete some Rows and because of that, you will have less then 35 Rows, so it would deaktivate the Freeze Panes.

Comment: @Indira and the benefit of this solution is, that it use the Events, so you don't have to run the Macro by hand, it will do this automatically on every sheet and you don't need to chagne the Code for every Workbook.

Comment: The unfreezing you have on the `Else` statement, should be within the `Worksheet_change` event so it indeed deactivates when you delete rows - that is, unless you wish to switch between sheets in order to trigger the event.